# Why a class can't find @Named provider from a Hilt module?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

I am migrating the application from Dagger2 to Hilt, and I started it from creating a single activity that uses Hilt

1. I wrote the inject annotation for one of the dependencies inside the activity

[image]

2. I have the provider method(it has a return type) in my HiltApplicationModule

[image]

3. configService is one of the dependencies provideRemoteConfig needs, so for that I also have a provider named method

[image]

4. Moreover, one of the dependencies that RemoteConfig also uses - it uses that same configService that we need to inject

[image]

5. When I run the build, I receive the error

   **@javax.inject.Named("config_service_merchant") com.example.configapp.ConfigService cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method** and

   **public interface ApplicationComponent extends AndroidInjector {
   ^
   @javax.inject.Named("config_service_merchant") com.example.configapp.ConfigService is injected at**
6. At this point, I am confused why it can't find it if I have the method

**My assumption that it tries to find it in Dagger2 modules and application components that I still have in the project, but I am not sure.**

***Why does configService's provider cannot be found to be injected in one of the classes(particularly AnalyticsConfig)?***

Comment: Did you find the solution ? I am also getting similar kind of issue.